# copybook misalignment in fileaid

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I am trying to create a copybook structure for my data file.

Part of the data looks like this

```
          C  0000.00
```

Since it has 0000.00 , in my copybook, we declared it as a PIC 9(04)v9(02).

but when i map it using fileaid, i get this error

```
15 EF-PURCH-FEE-AMT           6/AN   0000.0         
15 EF-FILLER4               975/AN   0
```

The decimal point is considered as another byte and the last zero is spilling into the subsequent field

I have tried to define the picture clause as zoned decimal by giving value as PIC ZZZ9V99 as well. But its still spilling into next field.

Expected result. :

```
15 EF-PURCH-FEE-AMT           6/AN   0000.00        
15 EF-FILLER4               975/AN   0
```

Actual result:

```
15 EF-PURCH-FEE-AMT           6/AN   0000.0         
15 EF-FILLER4               975/AN   0
```

PIC definition as of now:

```
15  EF-PURCH-FEE-AMT       PIC  ZZZ9V99.   
15  EF-FILLER4                PIC  X(975).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation for the PICTURE clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=clause-symbols-used-in-picture) of a data definition.  There you will find that the V is a presumed or virtual decimal point, not a physical one.  You may be able to attain your desired result with...

```
15  EF-PURCH-FEE-AMT PIC 9999.99.
```